# Android to I2C Control

Tags: usb, i2c, android

I have an I2C device that I would like to interface with Android. It seems that the easiest way would be to use a microcontroller compatible with Accessory Development Kit. But these kits and their microcontrollers are huge in size and I am looking for a solution which will work with a micro-USB and will fit in a form factor of 1 x 0.5 x 0.5 inch.

FT311 seems to be another option but it looks like an overkill for my application.

Is there any other option that I can use. I was hoping for something small like TI's MSP430 to work with Android.

Comment: Appears to be a shopping question. Those are off-topic.

Comment: How is the FT311D overkill?  You're going to be hard pressed to find a smaller, easier to use, or cheaper chip that has USB host functionality (as the Android interface requires)

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for an off the shelf development board that is going to fit in an area of 1" x 0.5", it's not gonna to happen. Even the smallest MSP board I could find is 1.9" x 1.9", doesn't have USB or I2C functionality, and doesn't even have a power supply:

[image: MSP Header board]

If that form factor is a hard requirement, then the board will need to be custom. The ADK is [open source](http://www.arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoBoardADK). So just take the schematic files and do the layout yourself to fit within your desired form factor.

Comment: Thanks for the help.I was planning to do the layout myself in the long run. But I wanted to start off with the smallest uC that would be of use to me. Maybe the question should have been, which is the smallest uC that can to USB->I2C with Android

Comment: @user16259 The [ATMega32U4](http://www.atmel.com/devices/ATMEGA32U4.aspx) has both USB and I2C with only 44 pins. In QFN package it's only 7mm a side. Since it's the same family it should be code compatible with the ADK. Although you have 1/8 the amount of memory to work with.

Comment: Notice that the bulk of the area of this board is given over to breaking out pins, the vast majority of which will not be used.  As such it's not really a meaningful answer - there are plenty of development boards out there which are smaller, and it's unclear that the chip on this board even has the necessary USB functionality.

Comment: @embedded.kyle - careful, the 32U4 has a USB **DEVICE** interface, while the ADK has a USB **host** interface provided by an additional chip.  Some Android devices can be USB hosts and thus talk to a device, but not using the ADK protocol which requires an external host.

Comment: @ChrisStratton You are completely correct in your statement. The OP makes no assertions as to the type of USB functionality needed and I merely attempted to state that the 32U4 was code compatible. Thank you for clarifying.

Comment: @ChrisStratton To your other comment, that MSP does not have USB functionality. I was simply using that board as an example of the smallest **off the shelf** board I could find. I thought pointing out the lack of a power supply would kill it outright from selection. But I've edited to more explicitly state that it doesn't meet any of the other requirements. If you know of "plenty" of **off the shelf** development boards that have a power supply, USB functionality, and are smaller that 1.9" x 1.9", I'm sure the OP would appreciate some links.

Comment: The 32u4 is most definitely NOT code compatible with the ADK as it lacks the part which makes the ADK an ADK, and its on-board USB is completely different in purpose and programming. I see no mention of power supply in that form factor in the question, however a regulator or even boost converter can be tiny.  There are small boards out there, though most are unsuited for this.  If a suitable chip is identified, a board can be made which is scarcely larger than the IC package.

Comment: @ChrisStratton Okay. Point taken about code compatibility. You clearly know much more about the ADK than I do. But you seem to agree with the **main** point of my answer. Which is that a board needs to **be made** to achieve the desired functionality. And in the original question, they asked for a "kit" which I took to mean a development board which does not seem to exist that satisfies all of the requirements.